# How can we change the button background color in UWP xbox app on selecting (focusing)

Tags: button, uwp, xbox

I want my button color to change when xbox select box is on the button. How can I achieve that? I haven't got an event on focus in Xbox UWP app.

Comment: please provide what you have tried and show the xaml code of your button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a **GotFocus** and **LostFocus** events on that button you are trying to do this.

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" GotFocus="ButtonGotFocus" LostFocus="ButtonLostFocus"/>
```

and in the code behind you can change the background color accordingly. you can also optionally check the **DeviceFamily** first if you want the behavior only on xbox.

```
private void GotFocus(object sender, object args)
{
    if(AnalyticsVersionInfo.DeviceFamily == "Windows.Xbox")
    {
        //change the color when the button gets focus
        MyButton.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }
}

private void LostFocus(object sender, object args)
{
    if(AnalyticsVersionInfo.DeviceFamily == "Windows.Xbox")
    {
        //change the color when the button looses focus
        MyButton.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
    }
}
```

more on **DeviceFamily** property : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.profile.analyticsversioninfo.devicefamily#Windows_System_Profile_AnalyticsVersionInfo_DeviceFamily

**Update**

if you want same effect on all or multiple buttons, just assign the events on every button you want the affect on like so :

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" GotFocus="ButtonGotFocus" LostFocus="ButtonLostFocus"/>
<Button x:Name="MyButton2" GotFocus="ButtonGotFocus" LostFocus="ButtonLostFocus"/>
```

and in the backend just replce **MyButton** with **(sender as Button)**

```
(sender as Button).BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
```

Comment: Thanks, its working. Anyway we could make this as a global function so that this can be used in the whole application?

Comment: yes , just assign the gotfocus and lostfocus events to every button in xaml. this way every button will get this behaviour and u have to write the backend events only once, but instead of using MyButton, just use sender as Button, see the updated answer